# Twitter search shows 15 results but has zero results

Tags: twitter

We are getting this response back from twitter api 1.1 search API for the following link.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/11/girl-scout-cookie-boycott-transgender_n_1199260.html

```
{
  "statuses":  [],
  "search_metadata":  {
    "completed_in": 0.12,
    "max_id": 420290345209847800,
    "max_id_str": "420290345209847808",
    "query": "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.huffingtonpost.com%2F2012%2F01%2F11%2Fgirl-scout-cookie-boycott-transgender_n_1199260.html",
    "refresh_url": "?since_id=420290345209847808&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.huffingtonpost.com%2F2012%2F01%2F11%2Fgirl-scout-cookie-boycott-transgender_n_1199260.html&result_type=recent&include_entities=1",
    "count": 15,
    "since_id": 0,
    "since_id_str": "0"
  }
}
```

How can `statuses` be empty when `count` is `15` ? Doing the same search through the web based search form results in plenty of results.